# Silenced gun sound

Tags: sound-design, sound, gun

Has anyone an idea about how to create the sound of a gun with a silencer fitted?
The type of sound you can hear in movies.

I heard that's it's not how this type of gun sound in reality so I'm wondering how they create that feeling of silent gun.

Comment: I tried things like using just small mechanic sounds with a muffled impact, but i'm still not very happy with it. I miss this little whistle that you can here at the end

Comment: for whatever its worth, there is a big (and free) library of actual suppressed weapons available over at http://freefirearmsfx.com./ it was kickstarted this year and went live a month or so ago. Good reference at the minium

Comment: Yes it's a very good lib but i'm not looking for a library but a way to create this sound that you can hear in many movies with this small whistle at the end. I'm not looking for a realistic sound but a more "common" sound

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a General Midi Gunshot (#128) played in a high octave.
Especially from Roland banks.

Here's a real silencer:

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with very short impacts, such as actual gunfire samples, drum hits, or other interesting impact sfx, then sweep a low pass or band pass filter down (again, very quickly) over it.  Play with the Q, start and end points, and the rate of acceleration that the filter sweeps (linear, logarithmic, exponential, etc).

Maybe try rapidly sweeping down the frequency of a sine wave oscillator to create the "chirpy" sound you want. Again, short duration and a quick attack is key here to keeping it from sounding too tonal.

The two above methods together is where I would start.